# couchbase backup not working -cbbackup

Tags: couchbase

I am using couchbase Version: 3.0.3-1716 Enterprise Edition. When I tried to execute the cbbackup below error is throwing. Please assist me on this.

Command

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./cbbackup http://Administrator:DuoS123@localhost:8091 /mnt/DK/
```

Error

```
2016-06-23 23:12:28,839: s0 error: async operation: error: create_db exception: database is locked on sink: /mnt/DK/(ObjectStoreBucket@192.168.2.192:8091)
error: create_db exception: database is locked
```

Comment: What is on /mnt/DK/ I ask as cbbackup will backs up to a SQLLite db. So the lock might be on that DB, not CB. Have you tried another location for the backup file to be created?

Comment: /mnt/DK/ is my mount location (network location). I need directly backup to the mount since I don't have space on  couchbase server.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely this is a limitation in SQLLite. You might be able to add something like nolock to the mount parameters if you are using NFS or what have you. Keep in mind that SQLlite cannot have 2 applications connecting to it at the same time. Check out #5 [here](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html).

Another solution might be to have one central backup node with local disk space to back up the cluster with.

Comment: This is how I have mounted my network drive to Linux (centos 6.5).
`mount -t cifs -o username=John,password=abcsd //192.168.3.11/Backup /mnt`
Can u help me on the parameter selection ? Thanks for the response :)